# This regex line exceeds my understanding "(?=(?:\d{3})++(?!\d))"

Tags: java, regex

i am pretty ok with basic reg-ex. but this line of code used to make the thousand separation in large numbers exceeds my knowledge and googling it quite a bit did also not satisfy my curiosity. can one of u please take a minute to explain to me the following line of code?

```
someString.replaceAll("(\\G-?\\d{1,3})(?=(?:\\d{3})++(?!\\d))", "$1,");
```

i especially don't understand the regex structure `"(?=(?:\d{3})++(?!\d))"`.

thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"(?=(?:\d{3})++(?!\d))"` is a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

It means *"only match if followed by ((three digits that we don't need to capture) repeated one or more times (and again repeated one or more times) (not followed by a digit))"*. See this [explanation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) about `(?:...)` notation. It's called non-capturing group and means you don't need to reference this group after the match.

`"(\\G-?\\d{1,3})"` is the part that should actually match (but only if the above-described conditions are met).

Edit: I think `+` must be a special character, otherwise it's just a plus. If it's a special character (and quick search suggests that [it is in Java, too](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/)), the second one is redundant.

Edit 2: Thanks to [Alan Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055885/this-regex-line-exceeds-my-understanding-d3-d/10056023#comment12868478_10056023), it's now clear. The second `+` means possessive matching, so it means that if after checking as many 3-digit groups as possible it won't find that they're not followed by a non-digit, the engine will immediately give up instead of stepping one 3-digit group back.

Comment: No, the second `+` is not redundant; it makes the first `+` [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

Comment: experimenting with "++" vs. "+" does not show any impact on the result, no matter what i put behind my integer (in java). so i guess it is really just a question of performance.

Comment: @dotwin that's correct for the current case, because if it steps back by 3 digits, the next character after the match candidate will obviously be a digit, so it will again fail. That's why `++` is added: to prevent this waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

this expression has some advanced stuff in it.
first , the easiest: `\d{3}` means exactly three digits. These are your thousands.

then: the `++` is a variant of + (which means one or more), but possessive, which means it will eat all of the thousands. Im not completely sure why this is necessary.

`?:`means it is a non-capturing group - i think this is just there for performance reasons and could be omitted.

`?=`is a positive lookahead - i think this means it is only checked whether that group exists but will not count towards the matched string - meaning it wont be replaced.

`?!` is a negative lookahead - i dont quite understand that but i think it means it must **NOT** match, which in turn means there cannot be another digit at the end of the matched sequence. This makes sure the first group gets the right digits. E.g. 10000 can only be matched as 10(000) but not 1(000)0 if you see what i mean.

Through the lookaheads, if i understand it correctly (i havent tested it), only the first group would actually be replaced, as it is the one that matches.

Comment: The possessive `++` isn't really necessary.  It makes the regex slightly more efficient (as @Lev observed), but I doubt you would ever notice the difference.  What makes it **correct** is the `(?!\d)`.  And the regex *will* match more than one group of digits; in `12345678`, for example, it will match first `12`, then `345`.

Answer (score 2):

To me, the most interesting part of that regex is the `\G`.  It took me a while to remember what it's for: to prevent adding commas to the fraction part if there is one.  If the regex were simply:

```
(-?\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3})++(?!\d))
```

...this number:

```
12345.67890
```

...would end up as:

```
12,345.67,890
```

But adding `\G` to the beginning means a match can only start at the beginning of the string or at the position where the previous match ended.  So it doesn't match `345` because of the `.` following it, and it doesn't match `67` because it would have to skip over some of the string to do so.  And so it correctly returns:

```
12,345.67890
```

I know this isn't an answer to the question, but I thought it was worth a mention.